# jQuery modal dialog not centering with position flag present

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-dialog

I have a site **[here](http://webfro.gs/south/dev/cloud/)**...

**I didn't create a fiddle because I'm not sure how to replicate the issue with ajax.**

When the site loads, there's an auto-popup that brings in an ajax request.

It's way off center and when I add the position flag there, the modal doesn't come up at all. I don't get any syntax errors, so I'm not sure what's wrong.

**With this code, the popup opens (but off center)...**

```
$(document).ready( function() {
    jQuery('#compliance').load('jquery-ajax.html').dialog();
});
```

**And when I add the position flag, it doesn't show up at all...**

```
$(document).ready( function() {
    jQuery('#compliance').load('jquery-ajax.html').dialog({
        position: {my: "center top", at:"center top", of: window },
    });
});
```

### **Edit-**

**This is what ultimately worked...**

```
    $(document).ready( function() {
        jQuery('#compliance').load('jquery-ajax.html').dialog({
        resizable: false,
        modal: true,
        width: 750,
        show: 'fade',
        hide: 'fade',
        position: {my: "center top", at:"center top", of: window }
        });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe your issue has to do with ajax being loaded into the modal box. This can cause content sizing issues among other things. You can try adding

```
jQuery('#compliance').load('jquery-ajax.html').dialog({
    resizable: false,
    modal: true,
    width:'auto'
});
```

Also for future reference, you shouldn't have to use `jQuery` when acting upon an element. You can use the `$` sign. If this isn't working then you may have an issue with the load order of your javascripts in the DOM

Answer (score 1):

A short timeout re-positioning the dialog did the trick for me. All other attempts failed.

```
setTimeout(function(){
    $("#dialog-selector").dialog('option', 'position', 'center');
}, 50);
```